# Select past records if no future records otherwise select first future record

Tags: mysql

I have the following database table and some dummy data:

```
id | doctor_id | patient_id | date

1  |     1     |    1       |  2020-06-06

2  |     1     |    1       | 2020-10-06

3  |     1     |    2       | 2020-10-06

4  |     1     |    2       | 2020-23-06

5  |     1     |    2       | 2020-25-06
```

I would like to select the last appointment for a patient if he has only past appointments or the next appointment if he has also future appointments.

In the above example the query should return record with id: 2 and 4 - last appointment for patient 1 because he has only past appointments and the first future appointment for patient 2 cause he has also future appointment.

How can I create these queries?

Comment: you should not use [reserved](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-A) names for column names.

Comment: In a database world it's more convenient to use `yyyy-mm-dd` as date format then `yyyy-dd-mm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just `doctor_id`, `patient_id` and the `date` then use conditional aggregation:

```
select doctor_id, patient_id,
       coalesce(
         min(case when date > curdate() then date end),
         max(case when date < curdate() then date end)
       ) date  
from tablename
group by doctor_id, patient_id
```

If you want the full row with the `id`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where (doctor_id, patient_id, date) = (
  select doctor_id, patient_id,
       coalesce(
         min(case when date > curdate() then date end),
         max(case when date < curdate() then date end)
       ) date 
  from tablename
  where (doctor_id, patient_id) = (t.doctor_id, t.patient_id)
);
```

You may change the inequality symbols `<` and `>` with `<=` or `>=` for the case that includes also the current date.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c2cbe521d95f7bf966dd154461fa03c8).

Answer (score 0):

Create two queries,

one which will return the last visit before today,

and another on which will return the fist visit after today.

after this you can combine both using the 'IF' (or `CASE WHEN`)

or, you could do this:

```
select patient_id, max(d) `VISIT`
from (
   select 
      patient_id, 
      case when `date`<'2020-06-20' then max(`date`) else min(`date`) end d, 
      case when `date`<'2020-06-20' then -1 else 1 end X 
   from visits
   group by patient_id,x) y
group by patient_id
;
```

i forgot to change '2020-06-20' to `curdate()`....